# applying changes to pod code source realtime - npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I have reactjs app running on my pod and I have mounted source code from the host machine to the pod. It works fine but when I change my code in the host machine, pod source code also changes but when I run the site it has not affected the application. here is my manifest, what I'm doing wrong?

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  minReadySeconds: 15
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp
        tier: frontend
        phase: development
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapp
        image: xxxxxx            
        command:
        - npm
        args:
        - run
        - dev
        env:
        - name: environment
          value:  dev
        - name: AUTHOR
          value: webapp
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /code
          name: code
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      volumes:
        - name: code
          hostPath:
            path: /hosthome/xxxx/development/react-app/src
```

and i know for a fact npm is not watching my changes, how can i resolve it in pods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what Rico has mentioned is correct, you need to patch or rebuild with every changes, but you can avoid that by running minikube without vm-driver here is the command to run minikube without vm-driver only works in Linux, by doing this you can mount host path to pod. hope this will help

```
sudo minikube start --bootstrapper=localkube --vm-driver=none --apiserver-ips 127.0.0.1 --apiserver-name localhost -v=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to reload your application everytime you change your code and your pods don't reload or restart when you change the code under the `/code` directory.  You will have to re-create your pod since you are using a deployment you can either:

```
kubectl delete <pod-where-your-app-is-running>
```

or

```
export PATCH='{"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"annotations":{"timestamp":"'$(date)'"}}}}}'
kubectl patch deployment webapp -p "$PATCH"
```

Your pods should restart after that.

Comment: brilliant, those works fine. i have came across this, so if i edit my code inside the pod npm does recomplie cause it's watching the changes, but host machine source is not being watch from the npm process. is there way to achieve this?